# theoretical question about search algorithms and data structures

Tags: search, binary-tree, binary-search, theory, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of N-dimensional features called M. I want to find in that list the matching feature to a query feature F. Comparing my features is not based on popular metrics (L1, L2, etc.): for instance, my feature distance between A and B is the result of comparing A with circularly shifted versions of B.

I've spent some time reading about search algorithms, I came to the conclusion that in my case, it is not possible to use KD-trees. Maybe no tree based search is suitable here (?).

What kind of search algorithm can I use to speed up the search as described above ?

Are fast search algorithms only suitable for popular distance metrics ?

Comment: Can you focus your question on *specific* items and *specific* comparisons? It is quite vague now, and it is impossible to say if *"maybe no tree based search is suitable here"*, as you hardly give any specifics about what that "here" is.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. To be more specific my features are histograms that contain the number of keypoints detected in the circular neighborhood around a range finder (2d Lidar). Such features are not rotation invariant. For instance, two histogram  features extracted from the same position will contain the same keypoints but there might be a shift between them due to a different sensor heading between the two acquisitions.

Comment: For instance feature A ={1, 2, 3, 0} and B = {3, 0,, 1, 2}. If I compare A and B using euclidean distance they will not match. However, when B is circularly shifted twice they will match since the distance will be zero.

Comment: Is there any gradation in how well two tuples match? Or are there only matches and non-matches (boolean)? Is there any ordering of tuples?

Comment: I cannot compare A and B directly. I need to compare A with all shifted versions of B to decide whether A and B are a good match or not.

Comment: A threshold on the distance between A and B is used to decide for a match. If the distance, as described above is below that threshold it is a match. The match decision is binary, however based on the distance one can sort possible matches from best to worst.

Comment: Distance is Euclidean distance after rotation ? i.e. √(Δx₀² + Δx₁² + Δx₂² + Δx₃² +...)?

Comment: And when you search, do you search for **a** match, or the *best* (closest distance) match?

Comment: I use a symmetric Chi2 distance after rotation. However Euclidean could be used as well. I look for the best match.